# PHP exif library, EXIF and IFD0 undefined

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

i'm trying to read metadata properties from jpg file, i have enabled extensions php_mbstring.dll and php_exif.dll in php.ini, i have also checked that both files is exist on folder ext. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $filename = '9g.jpg';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
$exif = exif_read_data($filename, 0, true);
echo "File Name: ".$exif['FILE']['FileName']."<br>";
echo "File Size: ".$exif['FILE']['FileSize']."<br>";
echo "File Date Time: ".date ("F d Y H:i:s.",$exif['FILE']['FileDateTime']);
echo "File Mime Type: ".$exif['FILE']['MimeType']."<br>";
echo "Device Make: ".$exif['IFD0']['Make']."<br>";
echo "Device Model: ".$exif['IFD0']['Model']."<br>";
echo "Image Width: ".$exif['COMPUTED']['Width']."<br>";
echo "Image Height: ".$exif['COMPUTED']['Height']."<br>";
echo "Image Resolution: ".$exif['IFD0']['XResolution']."<br>";
echo "Image Orientation: ".$exif['IFD0']['Orientation']."<br>";
echo "Software Used: ".$exif['IFD0']['Software']."<br>";
echo "Date Edited: ".$exif['IFD0']['DateTime']."<br>";
echo "Original Created Date: ".$exif['EXIF']['DateTimeOriginal']."<br>";
}
        ?>
    <body>
</html>
```

and here is the result, it is okay for parameter file but give me error for parametere EXIF or IFD0

File Name: 9g.jpg
File Size: 131678
File Date Time: February 11 2015 15:03:20.File Mime Type: image/jpeg

> Notice: Undefined index: IFD0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\coba_exif\index.php
>   on line 14 Device Make:
>
> Notice: Undefined index: IFD0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\coba_exif\index.php
>   on line 15 Device Model: Image Width: 1024 Image Height: 904
>
> Notice: Undefined index: IFD0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\coba_exif\index.php
>   on line 18 Image Resolution:
>
> Notice: Undefined index: IFD0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\coba_exif\index.php
>   on line 19 Image Orientation:
>
> Notice: Undefined index: IFD0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\coba_exif\index.php
>   on line 20 Software Used:
>
> Notice: Undefined index: IFD0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\coba_exif\index.php
>   on line 21 Date Edited:
>
> Notice: Undefined index: EXIF in C:\xampp\htdocs\coba_exif\index.php
>   on line 22

Original Created Date:

where is my wrong, any answer would be my appreciate

Comment: Can you show print `exif_read_data($filename)`?

Comment: here is the output for print(exif_read_data($filename)) : Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\coba_exif\index.php on line 10